# SELECT COUNT(*) return 0 but I have 800 rows

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I use Cassandra 2.0 and cqlsh:

```
cqlsh:node1> SELECT count(*) FROM users;

 count
-------
     0

(1 rows)
```

but when I do:

```
cqlsh:node1> select id from users LIMIT 10;

 id
--------------------
 8acecf2
 f638215
 8b33e24
 470a2cb
 0f9a5c2
 4c49298
 2e28a56
 b42ce98
 19b68c5
 2a207f2

(10 rows)
```

My users table have 5 "text" columns with more than 100Kb of base64 data.
When I do a `SELECT * FROM users;` cqlsh take 3 seconds before showing the data.

Any one has a solution?

Is it possible to make a `COUNT(column)`?

ps: what do you need? logs? where?

Comment: in first query you select count(*) from `users` table, but in seconds from `videos`

Comment: @Ilya Bursov I fix it, just an error of typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-think, why does your application need counts.  If you have millions/billions of rows, counting will be time/resource-consuming.

If your application is OK with "approximate" counts of users, then you may use "nodetool cfstats".  It will get you number of keys (users) estimate and generally accurate.

If you need "exact", then there are different techniques to do that.

- you can maintain a special row and keep adding columns to it, when there is a new row insert.  Now you can count the number of columns to get number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

what needs to be done when counting is specify a limit :

if you are sure that the number of "rows" is less that 5,000,000 (5 millions) then you can do in cql3.0 :

```
select count(*) from mycolumnfamilyname limit 5000000;
```

Comment: I specified a column name in place of (*) and used the above statement w/o the 'limit ...." designation; this works at least back to 2.2.3 with the above stated caveat for performance when used with millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

In order to count a specific column, you have to have the column in the `WHERE` clause.

For example, assuming the 'id' column is your primary key, you could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE id > '';
```

If the column is not the primary key, then you have to allow filtering as in:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM users WHERE name > '' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

As mentioned by others, this is slow and the `LIMIT` keyword is required if you expect a large number of users. The slowness comes from the fact that Cassandra reads all the rows one by one and from what I understand, it reads the entire rows (i.e. your really big columns will be loaded each time,) because they do not have a way to just read one column when filtering. But Cassandra 3.x may have a ameliorated that now.

If you really need that number often, you could use a lock and increment a field representing the number of users. You could also have a process that adjusts the number once in a while if it gets out of sync, somehow.